# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jsch/JSch in JAVA

Tags: java, weblogic11g

We have a code where we are trying to dump some file into sftp account of some user
for that, we use library  jsch from jsch-0.1.45.

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();  
         session = jsch.getSession(variable1,variable2); 
         session.setPassword(abcd);  
         session.setConfig(config);  
         session.connect();  
         channel = session.openChannel("sftp");  
         channel.connect();
```

I have added jar under WEB-INF-lib, still getting below error at line JSch jsch = new JSch(); when we deploy our application in WebLogic server.
Exception in thread "Timer-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jsch/JSch

> Blockquote

Could anyone help me, what causing this issue?

Comment: A NoClassDefFoundError does not necessarily mean ClassNotFoundException. Check the server log to find the complete error message, the stack trace and the root cause of your NoClassDefFoundError

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the WAR file contains this file as well.

You can also deploy the library to the WebLogic server as a library and try adding the library reference in the weblogic.xml